# How to search rows with corresponding date in newEntryIterable?

Tags: jackcess

How to search rows with corresponding date in newEntryIterable

Example :

```
Table table = db.getTable("Facture");                                                                        
IndexCursor cursor = CursorBuilder.createCursor(table.getIndex("DateIndex"));                             
for(Row row : cursor.newEntryIterable("01/03/2014")) {
   ...
}
```

No rows are returned, but there are rows with date = 01/03/2014 in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use `java.util.Date` and not string `"Date"`.

```
Table table = db.getTable("Facture");
IndexCursor cursor = CursorBuilder.createCursor(table.getIndex("DateIndex"));
Date search_date = Date('2014/03/01');
for(Row row : cursor.newEntryIterable(search_date)) { ... }
```